# Zend_Soap_Client doesn't work with proxy

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I'm accessing a SOAP web service like :

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client($wsdl_url, array('proxy_host'=>"virtual-browser.25u.com" , 'proxy_port'=>80));
```

Since my shared server blocks port 8888, I'm using this proxy server. But Zend Soap Client tries to directly connect it.

```
Exception information:

Message: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://abs..oup.com:8888/clsRSchedule.soap?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://abs..oup.com:8888/clsRSchedule.soap?wsdl"
Stack trace:

#0 /home/..../library/Zend/Soap/Client/Common.php(51): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://abslive3...', Array)
#1 /home/..../library/Zend/Soap/Client.php(1024): Zend_Soap_Client_Common->__construct(Array, 'http://abslive3...', Array)
#2 /home/..../library/Zend/Soap/Client.php(1180): Zend_Soap_Client->_initSoapClientObject()
#3 /home/..../library/Zend/Soap/Client.php(1104): Zend_Soap_Client->getSoapClient()
#4 [internal function]: Zend_Soap_Client->__call('ReturnDataSet', Array)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit** I see this [old bug](http://bugs.php.net/29211) which is marked fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I've had horrible problems with Zend's version and would only recommend using [nuSoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/)